# how clustered and non clustered index on primary key on same column can improve performance

Tags: sql, indexing

I have a non clustered index on column 'a' that is primary key. then if I create another clustered index on the same column. it improve performance with huge margin like from 16 seconds to 2 seconds? can anyone explain how this thing is happening ?

if I don't add new index and just convert the non clustered index that we have to clustered index then there is no improvement. how this is going on?

can't show code sorry!!!

Comment: Please show some code that creates the indexes. And also please edit the tags to indicate with RDBMS you are using.

Comment: @SamM . . . Not to mention the actual query whose performance seems to be improving.